# MongoDB aggregation `$group`: Specify a default operator?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm doing a `$group` within my aggregation pipeline, where I `$push` one property to an array, and for all the remaining properties I simply take the `$first`:

```
{ $group: { 
  '_id': '$_id', 
  property1: { $push: '$property1' }, 
  property2: { $first: '$property2' }, 
  property3: { $first: '$property3' }, 
  property4: { $first: '$property4' }, 
  property5: { $first: '$property5' }, 
  property6: { $first: '$property6' }, 
  property7: { $first: '$property7' }, 
  // …
}},
```

Is there a possibility to specify this in a more concise way? I am hoping for something like the following (which is not working), to say “use `$push` for `property1`, and `$first` for anything else”:

```
{ $group: { 
  '_id': '$_id', 
  property1: { $push: '$property1' }, 
  '*': { $first: '$*' }
}},
```

Comment: There is no other way. You have to specify each field with the `$first` accumulator in `$group` stage.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thank you -- feel free to post this below, I feel a negative answer is still an answer. As I wanted to avoid the hassle of having to list all property names, I went a workaround which involved `$replaceRoot` and `$mergeObjects`. I'll post details later on.

Comment: `$group` stage is the blocking stage in mongodb avoid as much as you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no other way. You have to specify each field with the `$first` accumulator in the `$group` stage.

But you can avoid specifying `$first` to every field. Something like this

```
{ "$group": { 
  "_id": "$_id", 
  "property1": { "$push": "$property1" }, 
  "data": {
    "$first": {
      "property2": "$property2", 
      "property3": "$property3", 
      "property4": "$property4", 
      "property5": "$property5", 
      "property6": "$property6", 
      "property7": "$property7"
    }
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above by Anthony Winzlet, there’s no way to achieve that through the `$group` operator. However, I used the following workaround, which saved me from having to list all those properties explicitly. It's probably not worth the hassle for a small amount of properties and if you do not need to take care of flexibility that additional ones might be added later, but in my case it made sense.

Here’s the idea of the aggregation pipeline:

1. Use `$addFields` to add the entire root document as a temporary copy.
2. Specify the group stage, where you add the `$push` for the desired property, and for the entire copied sub-document from before, use the `$first` operator.
3. Use `$replaceRoot` and `$mergeObjects` to take the copied root document, and replace the property with the `$push` aggregation.

Here’s an example:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  { $addFields: { tempRoot: '$$ROOT' } },
  { $group: { '_id': '$property1', 'property2': { $push: '$property2' }, 'tempRoot': { $first: '$tempRoot' } } },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ '$tempRoot', { property2: '$property2' } ] } } }
]);
```